# How do I access the binary matrix underlying an EdgeDetect output?

Tags: matrix, image-processing

Applying `EdgeDetect` to an image generates a black and white edge-detected image, which I suspect corresponds to an underlying binary matrix.  How can I access this underlying data structure, and map between a given matrix position and the corresponding coordinates in the processed image?  Ideally, I'd just like a list of, say, the $1$'s or $0$'s in the matrix (whatever corresponds to the white lines in the edge-detected image) and their coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ImageData[]`. Like this:

```
MatrixPlot@ImageData@EdgeDetect@ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]
```

[image]